# Is there any way of checking if a branch.io URL exists?

Tags: branch.io

We are using the Phonegap/Cordova library and the `createBranchUniversalObject` function for creating url's and then using the `showShareSheet` function to share it.

We've been requested to give the link an alias, ie https://cordova.app.link/iAmAnAlias

Since an alias is unique, the next call to `createBranchUniversalObject` for the same alias fails.

We're looking for a way to check if the alias exists and if so not to `createBranchUniversalObject` but just use that as the url. Only if the alias does not exis would we then `createBranchUniversalObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Branch Cordova SDK call that will check if an alias is already in use. If you plan for a user to always share the same link, you will have to implement some logic to store their referral link in your database.